# How to select a sub line from a line

Tags: qgis

I am doing a proifle analysis for a specific path and the selected path includes the path that is not the path of interest (bottom half). How do I filter out the path that I do not need from the selection?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't select parts of individual features so you need to split it into two.

1. Start editing,
2. select the line,
3. Split features tool and draw a split line finish with mouse 2,
4. save edits,
5. stop editing.

[image]

Comment: Just to add on for any ARM mac users when you click a single point when the splitting feature is enabled instead of dragging to create the line, for some reason QGIS crashes.